# Why does python evaluate the arguments of a function when defined and not when called?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was surprised to see that in Python, the classes in the argument list of a function, are instantiated when the function is defined and not when the function is called.

Consider the following code

```py
   class A:
       def __init__(self):
           print("init method called")

   def f(a=A()):
       print("function f called")

   f()
   f()
```

This will give the following output:

```
init method called
function f called
function f called
```

Thus, only one object of class A is constructed in this program, and not one for each call of function f.
Why is this, and is it a common trait for interpreted language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) or at other questions with similar topics:

- [What is the pythonic way to avoid default parameters that are empty lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366422/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-avoid-default-parameters-that-are-empty-lists)
- [Warning about mutable default argument in PyCharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686829/warning-about-mutable-default-argument-in-pycharm)
- [Python - mutable default arguments to functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255782/python-mutable-default-arguments-to-functions)

Comment: Thanks, Sparky05
I especially found this site insight full: http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm since I actually had the 'default value case' (I just din't knew it was a thing and what was the best way to handle it).